# Fantasy novel with giant hypnotising dragonflies and a young witch that has to keep her identity secret

Tags: story-identification, novel

Read this book a few years ago, it was a trilogy, the last of which was released sometime between 2008-2016. Female author I think.

Main character is a girl, in maybe her 20s, a witch of some kind, but she has to keep that a secret, because there are supposed to be no witches left.

The main conflict is these giant, flying, hypnotising dragonfly-like creatures, that started terrorising the land. If you look directly at them you are hypnotised and can't move and then they kill you.

There are a series of pillars in the northern region of the land, which everyone hates to go near, which used to keep out these dragonfly things, the pillars are decaying, hence why the dragonflies are getting through.

The pillars were supposedly made by the witches, who sacrificed themselves to make them, but in the last book it turns out all the witches were forced to do it against their will.

(It's not The Pillars of the World by Anne Bishop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

%99 sure your looking for The Magister Triology by C.S. Friedman

The elements dont match completely IIRC there were no witches until the main character becomes one there were male magic users, there were flying creatures that were very bad and there was a shield in place

> it turns out that the male magic users actually bond to the flying creatures somehow and use the life force of others to fuel their magic there were no female magic users because a female would have to bond to a female creature and all the female creatures were supposedly locked behind the pillars although I don't believe anyone actually knew this

Comment: Yes!! Thank you!! That was it. Clearly I forgot a bunch of details about the book, I now plan to read them all again, really enjoyed them the 1st time round!

Comment: Good books, read the first one when it came out then spent a while being annoyed the second had not come out yet.

Answer (score 5):

#### [*The Pillars of the World*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363777.The_Pillars_of_the_World) (2001) by Anne Bishop

It is the first book in the [*Tir Alainn*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40755-tir-alainn) series where the other books are:

- [*Shadows and Light*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47958.Shadows_and_Light) (2002)
- [*The House of Gaian*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47955.The_House_of_Gaian) (2003)

> Myth and magic combine in a superb dark fantasy of a world in danger of being destroyed by those who deny themselves and their heritage, and let evil loose in the world.
>
> In Sylvalan, a witch hunt is in full force. As witches and innocents are brutally murdered, magic is disappearing from the land, and the roads between the world of humans and that of faeries are vanishing one by one. Ari's family has tended one of the Old Places, places which hold the key to travel between human and faery lands, for generations, keeping the magic alive and the land lush and fertile. Ari unknowingly takes a Fae lover, the Lord of the Sun, and immediately becomes the target of the unwanted interest of the faery nobility.
>
> To save their world the Fae must trust humankind, but with a few exceptions they do not believe Ari and her friends can help them. Against the Inquisitor and the arrogant Fae, Ari and those who believe in the world of magic and human unravel the secrets of the Old Places and discover that they all need each other if any are to survive.

---

Found by Googling `book witches pillars dragonflies` although I was vaguely familiar of the work, I've probably seen other ids on it here before.

Comment: No that's not it, I had a look on Google too and this one came up, but I don't remember there being anything about Fae, and that book doesn't seem to actually have giant dragonflies...